# Power BI :: Edit interaction in cascade

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a a Power BI dashboard that you can download here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=D3y7qM)
- [.xslx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=r8tmf8)

**PROBLEM:** I want to complete these actions:

1. **Click on a matrix and select a cell: all other visuals change** (In the GIF you can see how I target August 214.96)
2. **Click on a pie chart: all visuals change but not the matrix and the pie chart** (I click on the orange part of of the pie chart which is 87.32 --> the next table should focus and show only 1 row with 87.32. Instead it's showing the total which is 464.20. And the pie chart is changing as well.)

[image]

Is this archivable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold the control key down when you do multiple clicks. When I do that in your .pbix, I get your desired result if I have understood your requirements correctly.

[image]

Comment: OK, so there is no other way around. I cannot use "Edit interaction" one after another? So the only alternative would be to instruct the audience to use `Ctrl`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by use edit interaction one after another but using the control key to cross filter datapoints is standard interaction technique. I usually dedicate a few sessions to user education once I have built my reports to show them things like this, drill down, drill through, focus mode etc.